# The alternatives command on FreeBSD (for choosing between versions of a package)

Tags: freebsd, alternatives

There's an `alternatives` command on Linux (man page section 1, `update-alternatives`), and there's a `select` subcommand on the `port` command from MacPorts.

Is there an equivalent on FreeBSD? Or do I have to manually manage the symbolic links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There cannot be a satisfactory answer without FreeBSD actually supporting this feature.

The best I manage to discover, is to install relevant "meta" packages e.g. `python3-3_3` for `python311-3.11.8`, list the files they install using e.g. `pkg info -l python3`, then manually edit the symbolic links. (The long form for the `-l` option is `--list-files`.)

My unsubstantiated guess is that, FreeBSD still position themselves as multi-user OS, so a system-wide version alias may not work for everyone. So yet another option for us, is to create a `bin` directory under user's own home directory, put a symlink in there, and add it to `PATH`.

Comment: What if some scripts require 3.9, another requires 3.11, and another old script needs 2.9?  On my systems, I simply install multiple versions of Python and let each script choose which version it wants to run via the shebang on the first line of the script.

Comment: @JimL. That's why I mentioned "yet another option" - put a symlink in user's folder and add it to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

The `alternatives` mechanism originated with Debian Linux. It should be easy to get the source and port it to BSD (but keep in mind that it isn't just symlinks to executables, different versions may have their own --incompatible-- set of configuration files/auxiliary programs/...).